# `with_dict expects a dict` - Ansible global composer and kosssi.composer

Tags: php, composer-php, ansible

I'm trying to use the [kosssi.composer Ansible role](https://github.com/kosssi/ansible-role-composer) to install a global composer instance as well as a couple of composer packages.

```
---
-
  hosts: myhosts
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: true
  roles:
    - { role: kosssi.composer,
        composer_path_env: true,
        composer_home_path: /opt/composer,
        composer_home_owner: vagrant,
        composer_home_group: vagrant,
        composer_global_packages:
          phpunit/phpunit: '@stable'
          phing/phing: '@stable'
    }
```

I've tried a lot of different ways of how to write this but I either get syntax errors or the error `with_dict expects a dict`. Looking at the source I see that `composer_global_packages` expects a dict with at least the length of one, it's defined like this:

```
with_dict: composer_global_packages
when: composer_global_packages|length > 0
```

Looking at the yaml documentation I also realize there isn't even such a concept as 'dict' or 'dictionary' defined.

**What am I missing? What's the correct way of listing the global dependencies?**

Comment: Everyone voting to close this question should leave a comment as to why they'd close this question. It's a pitty to finally write a question again on SO and to realize this bad habit is still in use.

Comment: The point of friggin SO is for developers to help each other, which is exactly what happened here and the whole thing has value for others too, everybody makes stupid small mistakes. The rigid closing mafia is one of the biggest problems SO has, what are you afraid of? Running out of disc space? It's not even YOUR disc space. :-( I've been here a long time, I see clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A dictionary is also known as an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Associative_arrays). There are two ways to define them in YAML, and you're mixing them up, which confuses the parser.

Either write the whole thing in JSON style:

```
-
  hosts: myhosts
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: true
  roles:
    - { role: kosssi.composer,
        composer_path_env: true,
        composer_home_path: /opt/composer,
        composer_home_owner: vagrant,
        composer_home_group: vagrant,
        composer_global_packages: 
        {
          phpunit/phpunit: '@stable',
          phing/phing: '@stable'
        }
    }
```

, or in whitespace-only style:

```
-
  hosts: myhosts
  remote_user: vagrant
  sudo: true
  roles:
     role: kosssi.composer
     composer_path_env: true
     composer_home_path: /opt/composer
     composer_home_owner: vagrant
     composer_home_group: vagrant
     composer_global_packages:
       phpunit/phpunit: '@stable'
       phing/phing: '@stable'
```

You can check your YAML structure with https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/

Comment: I see, thanks, good answer. Very clear case of me not understanding yaml... have never worked with it before.